# Opening a dataset in Carnets Plus

Tags: python, ios, pandas, ipad, jupyter

I have a iPad Pro with the M1 chip. I've tried to open this dataset several different ways on my iPad. I can open it on my Mac mini in the Jupyter Notebook environment. I have installed Carnets Plus on my iPad and I have saved the dataset to the Carnets Plus directory on my iPad (visible in the iPad files app). I have opened the dataset file directly in Carnets Plus but I cannot call it in the programing environment. I assume I don't have the path to the file correct in my code. I have tried opening the file from the original location from a website but that generates a parser error.

```
file_df = pd.read_csv('./network_data_CYB_674.csv')
file_df

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-c7026e26accd> in <module>
      1 #file_df = pd.read_csv('⁨⁨/iCloud Drive/⁨⁩⁨Classes⁩/674⁩/⁨⁩⁨project⁩/network_data_CYB_674.csv')
      2 #file_df = pd.read_csv('/Users/jksedik/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Classes/674/project/network_data_CYB_674.csv')
----> 3 file_df = pd.read_csv('./network_data_CYB_674.csv')
      4 #file_df = pd.read_csv('https://engage.utica.edu/learn/mod/resource/view.php?id=2075276', error_bad_lines=False, engine = "python")
      5 #file_df = pd.read_csv('https://engage.utica.edu/learn/mod/resource/view.php?id=2075276', engine = 'python')

/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/513EC314-F2E5-4B82-BE2F-B4B49E05C61D/Carnets-sci.app/Library/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision, storage_options)
    608     kwds.update(kwds_defaults)
    609 
--> 610     return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    611 
    612 

/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/513EC314-F2E5-4B82-BE2F-B4B49E05C61D/Carnets-sci.app/Library/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    460 
    461     # Create the parser.
--> 462     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    463 
    464     if chunksize or iterator:

/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/513EC314-F2E5-4B82-BE2F-B4B49E05C61D/Carnets-sci.app/Library/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    817             self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
    818 
--> 819         self._engine = self._make_engine(self.engine)
    820 
    821     def close(self):

/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/513EC314-F2E5-4B82-BE2F-B4B49E05C61D/Carnets-sci.app/Library/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1048             )
   1049         # error: Too many arguments for "ParserBase"
-> 1050         return mapping[engine](self.f, **self.options)  # type: ignore[call-arg]
   1051 
   1052     def _failover_to_python(self):

/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/513EC314-F2E5-4B82-BE2F-B4B49E05C61D/Carnets-sci.app/Library/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1865 
   1866         # open handles
-> 1867         self._open_handles(src, kwds)
   1868         assert self.handles is not None
   1869         for key in ("storage_options", "encoding", "memory_map", "compression"):

/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/513EC314-F2E5-4B82-BE2F-B4B49E05C61D/Carnets-sci.app/Library/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _open_handles(self, src, kwds)
   1360         Let the readers open IOHanldes after they are done with their potential raises.
   1361         """
-> 1362         self.handles = get_handle(
   1363             src,
   1364             "r",

/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/513EC314-F2E5-4B82-BE2F-B4B49E05C61D/Carnets-sci.app/Library/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py in get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, is_text, errors, storage_options)
    640                 errors = "replace"
    641             # Encoding
--> 642             handle = open(
    643                 handle,
    644                 ioargs.mode,

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './network_data_CYB_674.csv'
```

Comment: You can't open a file from another app in *your* app directly using a file path, even if the first app has exposed its files to the files app. The sandbox prevents this. You can either copy the file into your apps files using the Files app or use `UIDocumentPickerViewController` in your app to let the user select the file from outside the sandbox at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You might get a faster response by opening an issue on https://github.com/holzschu/carnets/issues or sending an e-mail to carnets_jupyter@icloud.com.

To answer your question: if the notebook and the CSV files are in the same directory, and both files are inside the Carnets Plus directory on the iPad, as you said, then it **should** work (because they are in the sandbox of Carnets Plus, and Carnets Plus has permission over its own sandbox). So it's either a bug in Carnets Plus, or the file is not what you think it is. For example, the Files app has been adding extra suffixes to some files, while hiding them to the viewer.

Carnets Plus has shell escapes, so you can debug the issue with `!ls` in a cell (it will show all the files), and `!pwd` (to check where you are) (`%ls` and `%pwd` will work, too).

If the notebook and the CSV files are in different directories, then that's the issue, although if the CSV file is in Carnets Plus own directory, you can access it with `~/Documents/network_data_CYB_674.csv`.

If the notebook and CSV files are in the same folder, but outside of Carnets Plus own directory, you have to grant Carnets Plus the access rights on the entire folder. You do that by clicking on the folder icon on the top toolbar, then navigating to the enclosing folder and clicking "Select".